# Spring boot with data jpa getting error on startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Getting an error while starting my Spring boot application. Here is a stack trace but I am unable to find the root cause. I am using spring boot 2.3.4 with spring data jpa. Any help appreciated.

```
{"timestamp": "12/21/2020 18:52:02:0871", "class": "org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator", "file": "JtaPlatformInitiator.java", "level" : " INFO", "line_number" : "52", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform], "method": "initiateService", "thread_name": "task-1"},
{"timestamp": "12/21/2020 18:52:02:0872", "class": "org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository", "file": "NamedQueryRepository.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "151", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": Checking 0 named HQL queries, "method": "checkNamedQueries", "thread_name": "task-1"},
{"timestamp": "12/21/2020 18:52:02:0872", "class": "org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository", "file": "NamedQueryRepository.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "167", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": Checking 0 named SQL queries, "method": "checkNamedQueries", "thread_name": "task-1"},
{"timestamp": "12/21/2020 18:52:02:0891", "class": "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry", "file": "SessionFactoryRegistry.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "52", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": Initializing SessionFactoryRegistry : org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry@263b5690, "method": "<init>", "thread_name": "task-1"},
{"timestamp": "12/21/2020 18:52:02:0891", "class": "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry", "file": "SessionFactoryRegistry.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "74", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": Registering SessionFactory: 64cd8993-8947-4c28-8a99-8717be785280 (<unnamed>), "method": "addSessionFactory", "thread_name": "task-1"},
{"timestamp": "12/21/2020 18:52:02:0891", "class": "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry", "file": "SessionFactoryRegistry.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "81", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": Not binding SessionFactory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured, "method": "addSessionFactory", "thread_name": "task-1"},
{"timestamp": "12/21/2020 18:52:02:0896", "class": "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl", "file": "SessionFactoryImpl.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "771", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HHH000031: Closing, "method": "close", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/21/2020 18:52:02:0897", "class": "org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope", "file": "TypeConfiguration.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "350", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": Un-scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope@3fbaa2e9] from SessionFactory [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@1741883a], "method": "unsetSessionFactory", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/21/2020 18:52:02:0902", "class": "org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl", "file": "AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "419", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries, "method": "deRegisterChild", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/21/2020 18:52:02:0902", "class": "org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl", "file": "BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "295", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries, "method": "deRegisterChild", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
Exception in thread "task-2" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
AbstractBeanFactory.java:322
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
AbstractBeanFactory.java:207
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:245)
AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:245
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:197)
AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:197
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:134)
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:134
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
AbstractApplicationContext.java:404
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361)
AbstractApplicationContext.java:361
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99)
DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.access$100(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:50)
DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:50
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.lambda$postProcessEntityManagerFactory$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:200)
DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:200
{"timestamp": "12/21/2020 18:52:02:0905", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource", "file": "HikariDataSource.java", "level" : " INFO", "line_number" : "350", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated..., "method": "close", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/21/2020 18:52:02:0906", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool", "file": "HikariPool.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "421", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Before shutdown stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0), "method": "logPoolState", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: I would suggest the most recent Spring Boot 2.3 version. (2.3.7.RELEASE) if that isn't possible add `spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default` to `application.properties` (or add that in anyway).

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried with the property option and the error is removed but the application is not started.

Comment: That is for another question. This was about resolving the error.

Comment: @M.Deinum, can you help me on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406134/spring-boot-application-is-not-starting

Answer (score -2):

Set the JAVA_HOME path and update JDK version. After that restart your server and it should work just fine!
If this doesn't work, check how many instances of tomcat you have. If you have more than one, shut them down.
It can also be a problem with the @Transactional annotation if you're using it wrong, you can see more details here- >http://www.javablog.fr/spring-transaction-visibility-proxy-propagation-required-and-requires_new.html

Comment: That won't help with a thing.